# pulseeffects get current preset in terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sound, scripts, shortcut-keys

I wanted to cycle through the pulseeffects presets with a keyboard shortcut instead of going to the app or command prompt. I can create a script(which will be called by a keyboard shortcut) to get all presets, current preset and load the next preset.

`pulseeffects -p` to get all the presets
`pulseeffects -l {preset}` to load the preset

The problem is I don't know how to find the current preset that is loaded so that I can go to the next one and there wasn't anything in `pulseeffects -h`

(I will be referring [this](https://gist.github.com/kapad/bdbf5df735690afd8cd36225becf7304) link for making the script and modify accordingly)

`Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on PulseEffects 4.8.4, which I built from source. On my Debian system, one can get the last output preset loaded (probably the current configuration if none were changed after loading it) using the following command:

```
dconf read /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/last-used-output-preset
```

PulseEffects has been renamed to EasyEffects from version 5.x.